# Real time Search /count occurence in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering, is there a way to create a real time search and count method in vba? (like webbrowser ctrl f)
I add a textbox on my worksheet and add this code to realise a search :

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Cells.Find(TextBox1.Value, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext).Row
```

That allow me to go to the first occurence on my document.
What i want is counting the remaining occurence and navigate through using button.
So i add a count code :

```
count = 0
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    Set Loc = .Cells.Find(TextBox1.Value)
    Do Until Loc Is Nothing
        Set Loc = .FindNext(Loc)
        count = count + 1
    Loop
End With
```

The problem i have is, it's slow and make my excel freeze if too much occurences are found (i work on a large file). Is There a better way to realise this kind of stuff?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction.CountIf` is much faster.

### Exact Match

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange, TextBox1.Value)
```

### Count cells containing string value

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange, "*" & TextBox1.Value & "*")
```

Reference: [MSDN - WorksheetFunction.CountIf Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx)

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thks

Comment: WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange, " * " & TextBox1.Value & " * ") to be exact :)

Comment: Your welcome.  FYI: your `.FindNext` loop is actually infinite.  You need to exit if when you get back to the original `.Find` or the process will start over see [MSDN - .FindNext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839272.aspx).

Comment: Good idea. I updated my answer per your comment. Thanks for accepting my answer.